# Does intercepting and replaying all system calls suffice to ensure deterministic program behavior?

Tags: linux, posix

On GNU/Linux it is possible to intercept all system calls of a program and its children using `ptrace(2)`. Typical software will rely exclusively on system calls to interact with other software.

**What are the possible sources of non-determinism a program can utilize that do not involve system calls? And are they commonly used?**

Typically, if I wanted to develop a *universal caching mechanism* which keeps track of all system calls of a program and its sub-processes, and I were to simply replay them, checking those calls return the exact same result (if not, I fallback to actually running the program), would that always behave perfectly as the genuine program?

More practically, if I relax some of the calls to allow for different behavior (typically, `brk` and `mmap` tend to choose different addresses and `getpid` return different process id, but they don't really affect program behavior much) are there commonly used programs that would break those expectations? (typically, I assume build tools tend to be rather deterministic)

Is there such an implementation of *universal caching mechanism* out there?

Comment: RDTSC comes to mind as a source of nondeterminism.

Comment: @Sneftel thanks. Seems like it can be disabled using the `PR_SET_TSC` argument to the `prctl()` system call, but it's a little bit evil (triggers `SIGSEGV` on access).

Comment: @Nonyme did you find anything on this topic